# Google Sheets IMPORTDATA() with no header

Tags: import, google-sheets

I'm looking over the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en) for IMPORTRANGE() to remove the header row, but it looks like I cannot do that.

How would I remove a header row from an external data source I'm bringing into Google Sheets using IMPORTRANGE() ?

Example data:

`A B C`

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

But I only want:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
=QUERY(IMPORTDATA(<myUrl>),
       "SELECT * OFFSET 1", 0)
```

Selects all but the first row of the CSV, works because the 0 argument makes it consider the header a row that is then skippable.

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(IMPORTDATA(<myUrl>),
      "SELECT * OFFSET 1", 0)
```

This works.

But this one does not:

> =QUERY(IMPORTDATA(),
>              "SELECT *", 1)

Clearly the optional [headers] parameter in QUERY() has a specialized meaning that has nothing to do with *eliminating* the header row(s).

From: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en:
*headers - [ OPTIONAL ] - The number of header rows at the top of data. If omitted or set to -1, the value is guessed based on the content of data.*

The docs should clarify what that parameter does to the data, i.e., that it will **merge** the specified value of rows into one header row.